# Create a Woocommerce product when post is created

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am using Woocommerce on my WordPress site. and I am Selling Various items on my site.

What I want is that every time I create a small post about a particular item.it also creates a Woocommerce product page with the one item available to be sold.

**For example:** I create a post about custom-made jewelry and I write a small post about it, and the customer can look at the post and buy it from the Woocommerce product section. 
Once the product is out of stock the post disappears"Hidden" until I have them in stock.

How this can be done? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your function file and replace empty strings with variable where necessary. This should solve your problem.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_create_product_from_post', 100, 2 ); 
function auto_create_product_from_post($id, $post){
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    //'post_title' => 'Adams Product',
    'post_title' => $post.post_title,
    'post_content' => $post.post_title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array() );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', '' );
}
```