# Create a WooCommerce product with the same name when a custom post type is published

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `Event` which I want to sell through woocommerce. So what I want, when I create a Event post, it automatically creates a product under woocommerce with the same name. Is it possible?

I tried the following code found in [Create a Woocommerce product when post is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766263/create-a-woocommerce-product-when-post-is-created)

```
add_action( 'save_event', 'auto_create_product_from_post', 100, 2 ); 
function auto_create_product_from_post($id, $post){
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    //'post_title' => 'Adams Product',
    'post_title' => $post.post_title,
    'post_content' => $post.post_title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array() );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', '' );
}
```

But the above code gives me `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string` error. I changed the action hook to `publish_event` but my website has gone in to a infinite loop and still creating a lots of products even after I removed the code.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong part is `$post.post_title`… `$post` is a `WP_Post` object so use `->` in `$post->post_title`, to get the post title as `.` is used for string concatenation in PHP.

So in your code:

```
$product = wp_insert_post( array(
    //'post_title' => 'Adams Product',
    'post_title' => $post->post_title, // <=== HERE
    'post_content' => $post->post_content, // <=== Changed
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );
```

This will solve your issue.

---

**A better way:** Since WooCommerce 3, you could use [CRUD Objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) like:

```
add_action( 'save_event', 'auto_create_product_from_post', 100, 2 );
function auto_create_product_from_post($id, $post){
    // Create an empty instance of the WC_Product
    $product = new WC_Product_Simple(); // <=== Simple product

    $product->set_name( $post->post_title );
    $product->set_status( $post->post_status );
    $product->set_description( $post->post_content ); // (optional)
    $product->set_short_description( $post->post_excerpt ); // (optional)

    // You can use any available WC_Product methods to set other properties
    // see: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

    $product->save(); // Save (publish) new product
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.